# Send email via excel online

Tags: excel, email, sharepoint, excel-formula, sharepoint-2013

I have two sheets. One contain the complete information and other sheet contain certain information about one student which has to be emailed. Please look at the screenshot below:

[image: The first worksheet]

[image: The second worksheet]

Here, the second worksheet has student id field where I want to be able to write the row number and fill the below blank with the correct information from previous sheet automatically. And then I want to be able to send that worksheet as email. I only know basic of excel and I am using excel online. Is there any way I could do it using excel online? I have searched a lot but could not find any solution. Please help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a macro to send the email, and then trigger it with a shortkey, manually or add a button that calls it. To create one, press Alt - F11 to open the Editor. Click Insert -> Module, and add the following code:

```
Sub SendEmail()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String


Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strbody = "Dear parent," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "This is your child's report:" & vbNewLine
          Cells(1, 4).Value & " :" & Cells(2, 4).Value & vbNewLine
          Cells(1, 6).Value & " :" & Cells(2, 6).Value & vbNewLine
          Cells(1, 7).Value & " :" & Cells(2, 7).Value & vbNewLine
          Cells(1, 8).Value & " :" & Cells(2, 8).Value & vbNewLine
          Cells(1, 9).Value & " :" & Cells(2, 9).Value

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = Cells(1,12).Value
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Student Report"
    .Body = strbody
    .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Whatever you put in `strbody` will be the body of the email. You can use the values of cells by using the `Cells(columnnumber, rownumber).Value` function. You can look at [this support page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Assign-a-macro-to-a-Form-or-a-Control-button-d58edd7d-cb04-4964-bead-9c72c843a283) to see how to use a button, or at [this page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-run-edit-or-delete-a-macro-fc5fb55d-124d-4cc7-bae0-111c9c26e234) to run it manually or with a shortkey. Double check by sending it to yourself first, edit it to your taste.